# Windows 10 Programs and Features Shows Duplicate Apps

Tags: windows-10

I have encountered an interesting issue. When I navigate to the programs and features panel in Windows 10, it shows that I have some duplicate applications installed even when I know for a fact that there is only one copy of the application installed. I am not sure when this happened, but I believe that this may have happened because I migrated my OS from a hard drive to an SSD so that I could get better read and write speeds. The transfer went amazing and I believe that this is the only problem that I have encountered. I am attaching a screenshot to better support my claims.

[image]

Note that when I try to uninstall one of the duplicate apps that it deletes not one but both listings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing preventing duplicates other than the registry key used to create the uninstall entry.

There are three locations that are queried to come up with the list for installed programs.

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

There can very well be overlap.

If you want to remove duplicates.. 
look closely at the keys and figure it out for yourself.